# A recursive function is entered to print smaller and equal numbers

Tags: python

I want to write this function, but it doesn't work

```
def less(number):
    while number>0:
        return less(number-1)

print(less(5))
```

Comment: I need a recursive function to print smaller numbers equal to the number entered

Comment: Hint - while using recursion you have to have somewhere line `return x` where `x` doesn't have anything to do with the original function - otherwise you will get `None` at the end **always**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use if instead of while. See the code:

```
def less(number):
    if number>0:
        print(number)
        return less(number-1)

less(5)
```